How to make my VLookup function use a cell value as the table_array ehich reference a table from another sheet
I am trying to make it so creating a new page is simpler for others when I leave my position. So I want to make sure they have to change as little as possible to generate new sheets. My work refuses to allow the use of macros as they tend to get excel files flagged and deleted automatically by the system(weird I know).
My formula in all E columns looks as follows:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B9,Table2029[[SN:[CTO Balance]], 7, FALSE)), 0, (VLOOKUP(B9,Table2029[[SN:[CTO Balance]], 7, FALSE))
B column is filled with unique member ID numbers that eliminates duplicates generated by last names causing issues.
The name of my sheets are the year they are for (ie this sheet is "2030" but is referencing the table on the previous sheet named "2029" and that sheets table is labeled "Table2029"
I have cell F1 being the same as the sheet name.
Cell G6 is =F1-1
Cell H6(for testing but failing) is ="Table"&G6 this does generate "Table2029"
I have been trying to use the indirect function and/or Cell reference every way I can think of but it breaks the formula.
Thank you in advance for any help. I will be leaving my position next summer and just trying to make things simple for me so I only get calls about the formula and not how to create new sheets.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This formula should work:
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B9,INDIRECT("Table"&G6&"[[SN]:[CTO Balance]]"),7,FALSE),0)

Or this one:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B9,INDIRECT("Table"&G6&"[[SN]:[CTO Balance]]"),4,FALSE)),0,
 VLOOKUP(B9,INDIRECT("Table"&G6&"[[SN]:[CTO Balance]]"),4,FALSE))

But this is an unnecessary complication.
